# Timer won't start when I raise timer.Start() event

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

This is the code block. I will explain details below.

```
public static bool isConnected;
    public MasterClient()    //Master Constructor
    {
         timer1.Interval = 1000;
         isConnected = false;
    }

    private void connectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {

            _ClientSocket.EndConnect(ar);

            //Global.Meuser = Environment.MachineName;
            BeginReceive();
            Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                tslStatus.Text = "Connected";
                btnConnect.Text = "Disconnect";

                tslStatus.Image = Image.FromFile(Global.path + @"\image\status\online.png");
                lbllocalIP.Text = _ClientSocket.LocalEndPoint.ToString();
                isConnected = true;
                //this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

            });

        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            isConnected = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (isConnected == false)
            {
                counter = 0;
                timer1.Start();
            }
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        isConnected = false;
        counter += 1;
        if (counter > 45)
        {
            counter = 0;
            timer1.Stop();
            AutoStart();
        }
    }

    public void AutoStart()
    {
        if (btnConnect.Text == "Connect")
        {
            if (IsRunning == false)
            {
                _buffer = new byte[8192];
                _ClientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                _ClientSocket.BeginConnect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(txtServerIP.Text), 9192), new AsyncCallback(connectCallback), null);
            }

        }
        else if (btnConnect.Text == "Disconnect")
        {
            if (IsRunning == true)
            {
                CloseClient();

                btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
                lbllocalIP.Text = "None";
                tslStatus.Text = "Disconnected";
                tslStatus.Image = Image.FromFile(Global.path + @"\image\status\offline.png");

            }

        }
    }
```

The timer should start after `timer1.Start()` event raised in the `finally` block in the `connectCallback` method.

When I check using a breakpoint, after `timer1.Start()` is called it will change to Enabled=true state.

I have taken the timer control from the toolbox and set its interval to 1000.

But still `timer1.Tick` event is not raising.

Condition: When server is not running at that time SocketException will fire, at same time I need to start timer so it will try after 45 seconds to connect to server again and if it fails it will be requeue.

Answer (score 0):

Before you call `timer1.start()` you need to attach event handler. I think it is missing in your code-

```
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
```

I would suggest do this in your constructor.

Also, you are calling `timer1.start()` when `isConnected == false`. I think you need to move `timer1.start()` outside of your if condition.

See if this helps.

Comment: I have taken control from toolbox and I already have that line in designer page.

`this.timer1.Interval = 1000;`
`this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);`

Comment: you are calling timer1.start() when isConnected == false. I think you need to move timer1.start() outside of your if condition.

Comment: I need to call it when exception being fire in try block. It will go to catch block and set `isConected=true` 
I am trying to do this through make sure inputting wrong ip address so it will throw SocketException.